# Multivariable Chain Rule: Finding ∂z/∂y and ∂z/∂x

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Question: The equation
$$7xyz=2x^2+y^2+3z^2+7$$
implicitly deﬁnes z as a function of x and y in the neighborhood of the point where $x=2, y=1$ and $z=2$ . 
Find ∂z/∂x and ∂z/∂y at this point.

Attempt at solution:

So I rearranged the equation to give me $$0=2x^2+y^2+3z^2+7-7xyz$$, then took the partial derivatives of ∂F/∂x/∂F/∂z, which got me $$\frac{4x-7yz}{6z-7xy}$$
and to get ∂z/∂y, I took ∂F/∂y / ∂F/∂z which got me $$\frac{2y-7xz}{6z-7xy}$$ Plugging in x, y, and z got me ∂z/∂x = 4, and ∂z/∂y = 13, but it's wrong. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It is very helpful that you posted your work. What is the chain rule for partial derivatives? Can you say how it applies here?

Comment: Must be
$$\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial x}}(x,y,z) = \frac{{4x - 7yz}}{{6z - 7xy}}$$
and
$$\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial y}}(x,y,z) = \frac{{2y - 7xz}}{{6z - 7xy}}$$